# What is the advantage of using express error handler?

Tags: express, error-handling

What is the advantage of using express error handler instead of handling the errors on the routes as they come as shown below. I am starting an [open source project](https://github.com/ujanja/mean) and I wanted to go with the best practices.

```
register: async function(req, res, next, error ){
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, async function(err, __user){
      try {
        if(__user)
          throw (
              {
                "type":"Registration Error",
                "details" : `The username "${__user.username}" is already taken. Try another one.`
              }
          )
      } catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).json( {"error":{"type":err.type, "details":err.details}} )
      }
```

Are there scenarios where it is better to use one way over the other?

To see the code above in its full context [click here](https://github.com/ujanja/mean/blob/master/server/controllers/auth.controller.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this article](https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-express-error-handling) there are definately benefits of using express error handler.

For instance:

1. you can manage all your errors from one place
2. You write less code.
3. You can group errors and manage them depending on their types.

You can get more info from the article. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in error handler in Express has a number of benefits:

1. It centralizes error handling in a single place, which makes it easier to maintain and update your error handling logic.
2. It allows you to handle errors in a consistent way throughout your application, rather than having to repeat error handling logic in multiple places.
3. It can help improve the readability and maintainability of your code by abstracting the error handling logic away from the main route handling logic.

In essence, instead of having try/catch and repeated `return res.status(500).json()` logic all throughout your routes, you handle errors in one place and only have to `throw` in said routes.